# Run animation when UIApplicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: ios, swift

I have problems running a animation when the application WillEnterForeground again. I have the animation running on viewdidload and it works.

The animations looks like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 30.0, delay: 2.0, options: .repeat, animations: {
        self.littleSunnyCloud.center.x += self.view.bounds.width + 80
    }, completion: nil)
```

The idea is to keep that animation repeating throughout the app.
But since something is happening when you multitask and go back to the app. Iv'e set up a notification for this like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(ViewController.doYourStuff), name:
    NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

This works and The method doYourStuff() looks like this, and it prints out when I get back to the app from multitask but clouds() which is the function with animation doesn't run

```
func doYourStuff(){
    print("reload animation")
    clouds()
    getData()
}
```

I have tried to put self. but didn't work either.
So how come this is happening? Why can't you run a animation
like this, what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, could ya try to explicitly run in on the main thread ? DispatchQueue.main.async { 
       doYourStuff()
}

Comment: Maybe wrap the `clouds()` in dispatch time of 0.5s to let the system finish animating the foreground transition then it would work

Comment: @Lepidopteron I tried this but it just started printing over and over really fast

Answer (score 3):

Try to continue animation on `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`.

*From documentation:*

> **UIApplication​Will​Enter​Foreground​Notification**
>
> Posted shortly before
>   an app leaves the background state on its way to becoming the active
>   app.

Apple does not tell what's happening under the hood but I think runloop "shuts down" when application goes to background and does not exist on `WillEnterForeground` when app restores it's state so it's not the right moment to do UI refreshing/resume animations.

*From documentation:*

> **application​Did​Become​Active(_:​)**
>
> You should use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or
>   not yet started) while the app was inactive. For example, you could
>   use it to restart timers or throttle up OpenGL ES frame rates. If your
>   app was previously in the background, you could also **use it to refresh
>   your app’s user interface**.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I changed the my notification for DidBecomeActive instead but still it doesn't work. Why isn't there a option to just start UI animations again when the app is active again. It's seems strange that something that could be simple is so hard to do. Whatever I do I can't get the animation running again.

Comment: @DoubleSpace application​Did​Become​Active is the right place. Maybe you can share your project? I'll be able to see what's the problem.